# Meteor mongodb data pivot and more elegant code

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I have a bin with all the relevant details here: http://jsbin.com/ribor/1/edit?js,output

But for SO answering ease here are the details. I have these model examples:

```
Orders = {
  _id: "T487wBz7Pvzjo2QHh",
  beverages: [
    { 
      _id: "8ea26bb103efae385f80f881",
      delivered: false,
      name: "Wine",
      units: "55"
    }
  ],
  location: "yTKWLFwSDvp3DyCkx",
  locationName: "Ladies Garden",
  locationNumber: "101",
  timestamp: 1398393004864,
  user_id: "W3Fdq36Ts2TdWxCRP",
  username: "jgeezy"
};

Locations = {
  _id: "yTKWLFwSDvp3DyCkx",
  beverages: [
    {
      _id: "e5552a68266ed76895b8228a",
      fillTo: "10",
      name: "Wine Coolers",
      orderWhen: "10",
      startUnits: "10"
    }
  ],
  name: "Teen Cabana",
  number: "103",
  organization: "Super Happy Teens!",
  vendor: false
};
```

I need to render some rows in a table per location that will show the total # of undelivered beverage orders per location. I have this function written already:

```
Template.dashboardOrders.undeliveredOrders = ->
  undeliveredOrders = Orders.find({'beverages.delivered': false}, {
    transform: (order) ->
      order.unfilledOrders = 0
      _.each order.beverages, (bev) ->
        if not bev.delivered
          order.unfilledOrders += 1
      order
  })
```

But that gives me an array sorted by Order & timestamp. The output I am looking for is an array sorted by unique location & timestamp. Not entirely sure how to get there, but I've been trying different map & reduce approaches as I sense that is the way to go, but I am stuck. Any help is much appreciated!

*BONUS* Also, my approach feels unelegant due to having to return the order object and use += to increment. I sense there might be a nicer way to do this.

Comment: This is relatively easy using underscore methods `groupBy` or `groupBy`, depending on what you want, but I don't quite understand the question.  Do you want the total # of undelivered beverage orders by location (i.e. `countBy`), or an array sorted by location AND timestamp (i.e. `groupBy`)?  They're obviously going to be two different things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm just going to add a second answer to respond to @jasongonzales' second question. My first answer, just the query, returned all the orders that are undelivered and sorted them by location and timestamp. Per the comment, the following is also desired:

> I want to include all the orders that are undelivered per location and I need a count of the undelivered orders per location.

There are many ways to achieve that. I think the easiest is to not try to crowd it all into the query, but rather work with the data returned by the query:

```coffee
Template.dashboardOrders.undeliveredOrdersByLocation = ->
  orders = Orders.find
      beverages.delivered: no
    ,
      sort:
        location: 1
        timestamp: 1

  # Create an object, locations, to hold the undelivered orders by location;
  # the object keys are the location _id's, and the values are the mongo docs:
  locations = {}

  # Loop through all the undelivered orders and add each to the locations object:
  orders.forEach (doc) ->
    unless locations[doc.location]?
      locations[doc.location] =
        undeliveredOrders: []
        undeliveredOrdersCount: 0
        location: doc.location
        locationName: doc.locationName
        locationNumber: doc.locationNumber
        # etc., whatever else your template needs

    locations[doc.location].undeliveredOrders.push doc
    locations[doc.location].undeliveredOrdersCount++

  # Convert the locations object into an array for use in your template:
  return _.values(locations) # Don't need to preserve the keys
```

You didn’t give an example of your template, but you could use the `locations` array like so:

```html
{{#each undeliveredOrdersByLocation}}
  There are {{undeliveredOrdersCount}} undelivered orders for {{locationName}}:
    {{#each undeliveredOrders}}
      An order submitted by {{username}} on {{timestamp}} for:
        <ul>
          {{#each beverages}}
            <li>{{units}} units of {{name}} need to be delivered.</li>
          {{/each}}
        </ul>
    {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

Comment: Noooooooooooice! Green check mark for you my brother.

Comment: Thanks. You could avoid the adding of extra properties onto the object by creating more helpers to retrieve the length of the .undeliveredOrders array etc. It doesn't really affect performance, it's just how you prefer to organize your code.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just:

```
Template.dashboardOrders.undeliveredOrders = ->
  Orders.find
      beverages.delivered: no
    ,
      sort:
        location: 1
        timestamp: 1
```

?

And if you really want an array instead of a cursor, add `.fetch()` to the end.

Comment: Thanks for the more elegant query, but it still only gets me part of the way there. I want to include all the orders that are undelivered per location and I need a count of the undelivered orders per location.